# Using typeof in Event Listener

Tags: javascript

I would like to console log info if my value which I'm input is a number. Unfortunately it doesn't work and any bug isn't appear as well.

Following snippet pulled from the CodePen link (https://codepen.io/matoung/pen/KBNmPP)

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.buttonClass');


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let myValue = document.querySelector('.inputClass').value;
    if(typeof myValue === 'number'){
        console.log('To jest liczba');
    }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container-6 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Random</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class='inputClass' />
<input type="button" value="Wyślij" class="buttonClass"/>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be a number</p>
 </div>
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be a string</p>
 </div>
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be a boolean</p>
 </div>
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be an array</p>
 </div>
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be an undefined</p>
 </div>
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be a null</p>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your code properly to your question?

Comment: You should try with this condition instead: `if(!isNaN(parseInt(myValue))){
        console.log('To jest liczba');
    }`

Comment: it will always be a `string`

Answer (score 2):

You can check for number using [isNaN](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan_number.asp)

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.buttonClass');


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let myValue = document.querySelector('.inputClass').value;
    
    if(!Number.isNaN(parseInt(myValue))){
        console.log('To jest liczba');
    }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container-6 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Random</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class='inputClass' />
<input type="button" value="Wyślij" class="buttonClass"/>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be a number</p>
 </div>
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be a string</p>
 </div>
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be a boolean</p>
 </div>
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be an array</p>
 </div>
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be an undefined</p>
 </div>
 <div class="container-6">
  <p>It will be a null</p>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hari has already given a perfectly correct answer. However, if you want to be able to detect more than just `number` types, you can use `JSON.parse` like so:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let myValue = document.querySelector('.inputClass').value;

    try {
        myValue = JSON.parse(myValue);
    } catch (parseError) {
        // myValue does not hold a valid JSON string, so it must be any arbitrary string.
        // You can choose to define what constitutes as 'undefined' here.
    }

    if (typeof myValue === 'number'){
        console.log('To jest liczba');
    } else if (typeof myValue === 'boolean') {
        console.log('This is a boolean');
    } // etc.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) together with [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Something like:

```
let number = +myValue;
if (number === parseFloat(myValue) && !isNaN(number)) {
  // is a number, then you can use `number` if you neeed it
}
```

The reason why the code use all of those three method, is to cover any scenario:

1. `parseFloat` converts up to the first not numeric character: it means `12.10px` is parsed to a valid `12.10`, where `+"12.10px"` returns `NaN`.
2. the unary operator converts empty string "" to 0, where `parseFloat` returns `NaN` – which in our case is correct.
3. In case they both returns `NaN` we have to call `isNaN` to don't have false results.

That should cover almost all the scenarios.
However, keep in mind that in JS a string like `"0x10"` *is* a valid number (16, hex), as for `"0.0314E+2"`. If you want to only have regular floating number in the form `00.0`, then you need a regular expression instead. Something like:

```
if (/^\d*\.?\d+$/.test(myValue)) {
  // is a number, then you can convert with the unary operator
  let number = +myValue;
}
```

If you want only integer, the regexp is more straight forward, it's just `/^\d+$/`.

Hope it helps!